# How to use the same background color as in class mat-app-background?

Tags: angular-material

I use theming of angular material. In body I use "mat-app-background" as class which sets the background color to `#fafafa`. How can I access this value as a variable?
I tried

```scss
$background-palette: map-get($theme, background);
$background: mat.get-color-from-palette($background-palette, 0);
```

but getting `#ffffff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close to the solution, you just need to use the `background` value from the `$background-palette`, instead of `0`:

```scss
$background-palette: map-get($theme, background);
$background: mat.get-color-from-palette($background-palette, background);
```

This is also what Angular Material does internally for the `.mat-app-background` class, see [their source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/22b03c008620584c5541b236909e37415c36730f/src/material/core/_core-theme.scss#L26).

StackBlitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ykdetz?file=src%2Ftheme.scss